# Biding an Angular method to HTML disable attribute doesn't work

Tags: angular

In my html I want to make a button to get disable when I get to the and of a pagination.

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="disable()">
```

So I created a Service with a method to to this

```
public getDisable() {
 const curr = this.getCurrent();
 return ((curr.index + 1) == (this._pages.length)) ? true : false;
}
```

In the file where is the button, the ts one, I inject the service and use the getDisable() to use in button.

```
public disable() {
 this.MyService.getDisable();
}
```

I put in the console every variable and when I get to the end of the array, meaning this

```
((curr.index + 1) === (this._pages.length))
```

is true(in the console I get 3 === 3), the button doesn't get disabled.

Comment: What angularjs version are you using?

Comment: Just use `ngDisabled`.

Comment: I use Angular 4.0. I saw in an angular 4 tutorial this, but looks like doesn't work, even for the professor worked.

Comment: Didn't you forget to `return` value from your `disable()` method?

Comment: Ok you were right. With return put there, when I click next in the end of the array I get the next button disabled, but as well the prev button, too. Why :)? Both buttons, prev and next, have this method [disabled]="disable()".

Comment: You're asking questions about code that you didn't post.

Comment: ok, thank you guys for that clarification.